# is primary key (a,b) different from primary key (b,a)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have an `employee` and a `supervisor` table. A supervisor is an employee. The `employee` table looks like this:

```
employee_id | employee_name
1           | Freeman
2           | Manfred
```

The `supervisor` table looks like this (fields are foreign keys to `employee` table):

```
supervisor_id | employee_id
1             | 2
2             | 1
```

I implemented a composite primary key (supervisor_id,employee_id) and that didn't prevent the update.

How can I prevent the above from happening? An employee cannot supervise his/her supervisor.

Comment: You'll need to add a constraint to your table. Primary keys don't work that way

Comment: so remove the composite primary key?

Comment: @F.Hall: you still want some sort of primary key, but it won't be able to do everything you need.

Comment: @F.Hall No, I would keep it. This kind of linking typically has a composite primary key - in that the link between a supervisor is unique, fully identifies the row, and should be indexed. However, you would also need to add a constraint to prevent an employee being a supervisor of their supervisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no user interface that needs to be notified then the event the validation fails, siride's solution using triggers is a good one, Gordon Linoff solution would also work.  A simpler solution, that would also be able to notify a user interface that the data failed validation would be be to update the table using a stored procedure....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddSupervisor
(
   @supervisor_id int,
   @employee_id
)
AS
    INSERT INTO supervisor
    SELECT @supervisor_ID, @employee_id
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM supervisor
        WHERE
            supervisor_id = @employee_id AND
            employee_id = @supervisor_id
    ) AND NOT EXISTS  -- EDIT - Add logic to stop inserts for employees who already have a supervisor
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM supervisor
        WHERE
            employee_id = @employee_id
    )

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Selecting @@ROWCOUNT at the end will return 0 if no rows were inserted or 1 if a row was inserted.  You might argue that you could combine this answer with a trigger or constraints to ensure that validation isn't circumnavigated by using something other than the stored proc to update the table.

EDIT:  If an employee can only have one supervisor, rather than having a separate supervisor table, you should just have a supervisor_id column in the employee table.  Having a separate Supervisor table with a composite key would cater many to many relationships i.e.  Supervisors supervising multiple employees and employees having multiple supervisors.

Comment: but this allows for one employee to have more than one supervisors... how can i ensure that an employee has one and only one supervisor?

Comment: @F.Hall I've updated the answer to add a clause that will exclude inserts for employees who already have a supervisor.  The logic in a corresponding trigger would be very similar.

Comment: a supervise b and b supervise c, how can i prevent c from supervising a?

Comment: @F.Hall that's a little more tricky.  Perhaps this would help....

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45158/how-to-write-a-query-which-finds-all-circular-references-when-a-table-references

Answer (score 3):

This isn't easily possible purely with primary keys or check constraints.

- Primary keys are unique constraints that specify that no row may have the same primary key as any other row. But it doesn't say that certain combinations are invalid.
- Check constraints can use more complex logic, but only about values of columns in the row about to be inserted. Your problem requires looking at other rows. (But see Gordon Linoff's answer for how you could do this with constraints -- even though it's a bit opaque).

The solution is to use a trigger. The trigger can check other rows in the table to see if the employee is already being supervised and cancel the transaction.

Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a couple of ways.  One is to impose check constraints on the ordering of the values and use a unique constraint (or primary key).  This would be:

```
alter table supervisor add constraint chk_supervisor_employee check (supervisor_id < employee_id);
```

This creates the functionality.  But it doesn't do what you want semantically.  Instead, you can add columns to get the least and greatest, and then add a unique constraint:

```
alter table supervisor add minse (case when supervisor_id < employee_id then supervisor_id else employee_id end);
alter table supervisor add maxse (case when supervisor_id < employee_id then employee_id else supervisor_id end);
alter table supervisor add constraint unq_supervisor_employee unique(minse, maxse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. Composite key means that your key is pair of two values.

Pair a is equal to Pair b only if and only if pair a first attribute is equal to pair b first attribute and pair a second attribute is equal to pair b second attribute.

What you need is a well constraint not a primary key.
And let me warn you just in case that constraint that prevents inserting (a,b) pair if pair (b,a) is already in table won't solve your problem because of transitivenes of supervision realation.

What i mean is: let a be a supervisor of b and b supervisor of c. Shall c be able to be a supervisor of a?

Answer (score 0):

> how can i ensure that an employee has one and only one supervisor?

Make employee_id your primary key in the supervisor table (not supervisor_id and employee_id).